# $T$:($u$ $\otimes$ $v$) $=$ ($T$.$v$).$u$ in tensorial notation

Tags: tensors

I was reading this [article](https://sbrisard.github.io/posts/20140219-on_the_double_dot_product.html), and then I stopped by this equality:

$$\mathbf{T}:(\mathbf u \otimes \mathbf v)=(\mathbf{T}\cdot \mathbf v)\cdot \mathbf u$$

$\mathbf{T}$ is 4th order, $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are 2nd order tensors.

How can we prove this equality using tensorial notation?
I am convinced regarding the count of the order of tensors on both sides, that both yield a second order tensor by contraction of indices.

Comment: Have you tried just writing it out w/ Einstein summation convention? e.g. $\langle\mathbf u\otimes \mathbf v\rangle_{ij}=u_iv_j$. I think it falls out more or less instantly from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order not to confuse them with vectors I will use A,B instead of u,v.

Remember that $$(A\otimes B)^{ij}{}_{kl}=A^i{}_jB^k{}_l$$
So
$$\big(T:(A\otimes B)\big)^{ij}{}_{kl}=T^{ij}{}_{pq}(A\otimes B)^{pq}{}_{kl} \\ =T^{ij}{}_{pq}A^p{}_kB^q{}_l \\ =(T\cdot A)^{ij}{}_{qk}B^q{}_l \\ =\big((T\cdot A)\cdot B\big)^{ij}{}_{kl}$$
Thus
$$\mathbf{T}:(\mathbf A\otimes  \mathbf B)=(\mathbf T\cdot \mathbf A)\cdot \mathbf B$$

Comment: Thanks! So, to make sure I understand well, since $A$ and $B$ are both 2nd order, then their cross product is a 4th order, after that when doubled product with $T$ which is of 4th order, it should give us 2nd order, but why is the result 4th order?

Comment: @user134613 The doubled product collapses two indices; in the case where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are vectors (which is what the notation in the book seems to suggest) and $T$ is a fourth order tensor, then the result will be second order — $(4-2)+((1+1)-2)$. Here where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are second order (as you note), their tensor product is fourth order, so the order of the result is $(4-2)+(4-2)=4$.

Comment: In the general case, if $\mathbf{T}, \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}$ are orders $t, a, b$ respectively, then the order of $\mathbf{T}:(\mathbf{A}\otimes\mathbf{B})$ is $(t-2)+((a+b)-2) =t+a+b-4$ and the order of $(\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{A})\cdot\mathbf{B}$ is $((t-1)+(a-1)-1)+(b-1)=t+a+b-4$.

Comment: thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It's not a cross product, it's a tensor product.